# Player on Player collision in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a collision detection between 4 controllable characters on an RPG battle map. Here is the function I'm using

```
def player_collission(Lord_x,Lord_y,Journeyman_x,Journeyman_y,Archer_x,Archer_y,
                  Cleric_x,Cleric_y):
print("Running")
if abs(Lord_x - Journeyman_x) <= 0 and abs(Lord_y - Journeyman_y) <= 0:
    print("Colission detected")
    return True
elif abs(Lord_x - Archer_x) <= 0 and abs(Lord_y - Archer_y) <= 0:
    print("Colission detected")
    return True
elif abs(Lord_x - Cleric_x) <= 0 and abs(Lord_y == Cleric_y) <= 0:
    print("Colission detected")
    return True
elif abs(Journeyman_x - Archer_x) <= 0 and abs(Journeyman_y - Archer_y) <= 0:
    print("Colission detected")
    return True
elif abs(Journeyman_x - Cleric_x) <= 0 and abs(Journeyman_y - Cleric_y) <= 0:
    print("Colission detected")
    return True
elif abs(Archer_x - Cleric_x) <= 0 and abs(Archer_y == Cleric_y) <= 0:
    print("Colission detected")
    return True
else:
    return False #I didnt use classes so it has alot of if statements


if player_up:
    p_collide = player_collission(Lord_x,Lord_y,Journeyman_x,Journeyman_y,Archer_x,Archer_y,
                  Cleric_x,Cleric_y)
    if current_player == "lord":
        if p_collide != True:
            Lord_y -= tile_increment
        if Lord_y <= 0:
            Lord_y = 50
```

What happens is that the characters still move into each other but it detects the collision after it has already moved into each other and freezes all movement. I'm not sure how to re arrange it to make it work properly.

Comment: I bet `abs(Lord_y == Cleric_y) <= 0` is a typo.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Also, `if ... =! True:` is doubly wrong; Just use `if not ... :` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You detect collision when it has already happened. This is why you see characters overlapping.

Instead, you should detect if a collision is *going to happen,* an prevent a motion that would lead to that.

An example:

```py
def move(coords, velocity):
  """Moves coords according to velocity."""
  x, y = coords  # Unpack a 2-tuple.
  vx, vy = velocity
  return (x + vx, y + vy)

tom_coords = (0, 0)  # Tom is in the corner.  
tom_v = (1, 1)  # Tom moves by diagonal.

jerry_coords = (5, 0)  # Jerry is a bit away from Tom.
jerry_v = (0, 1)  # Jerry moves vertically.

while True: 
  new_tom_coords = move(tom_coords, tom_v)  # Tom moves without fear.
  new_jerry_coords = move(jerry_coords, jerry_v)
  if new_jerry_coords == new_tom_coords:  # Would be a collision!
    new_jerry_coords = jerry_coords  # Back to previous tile.
    vx, vy = jerry_v
    jerry_v = (-vx, -vy)  # Jerry runs back.
    print("Collision imminent, Jerry runs away!")
  else:
    jerry_coords = new_jerry_coords  # Only update if no collision.
  # Could also check collisions with walls, etc.
  tom_coords = new_tom_coords
  # Not inside pygame, so just print it and wait for a key press.
  print('Tom:', tom_coords, 'Jerry:', jerry_coords)
  input("Enter to continue, Ctrl+C to stop ")
```

Run it in and see how Tom and Jerry come close to each other but never occupy the same tile.